# sorting by a related item with ming on mongodb

Tags: python, orm, mongodb, turbogears2, ming

### setup

A TurboGears2 project using ming as an ORM for mongodb. I'm used to working with relational databases and the Django ORM.

### question

Ming claims to let to interact with mongodb like it's a relational database and a common thing to do in a relational database is sort a query by a property of a foreign key. With the Django ORM this is expressed with double underscores like so: `MyModel.objects.all().order_by('user__username')`

**Is there an equivalent for this in ming?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used ming, but they seem to have a `sort` method that you can add to a query, check it out [here](http://merciless.sourceforge.net/tour.html#querying-the-database), not much in the form of documentation

I use [mongoengine](http://mongoengine.org/), it has great documentation and its very similar to the django ORM

Comment: Thanks @MattoTodd but I guess I should have specified that I'm aware of the `sort` method and have seen the documentation but still can't figure out how to sort using a related property

Comment: not sure how deep you are, but I can only recommend mongoengine. Querying is a breeze. The query would match the django orm version in this case

Comment: I'm the new guy on an already established project so switching it out may not be an option.

Comment: sorry bro. like I said, not sure how deep you are in using ming,  if it's already well established, then someone else on your team must have made a simlar query before. if its not well established, recommend mongoengine and you'll be a hero.